# C# .Net Socket Keep Alive time?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sockets, timeout

Newbie question here.. Just trying to be sure here..

This is **not** a HTTP Keep-Alive question.

Is there a way to make sure a socket gets closed() after a certain amount of time.

Why i'm asking this because if I just close socket right away.. the client may not receive the packet to indicate like incorrect password etc..

Is there any timeout like built in command inside Socket?

I'm trying to avoid building a timer or event to close it off thinking of a alternate solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never tried it myself, but there is `LingerOption`.

Take a look at [Socket.LingerState Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.lingerstate.aspx).

> This property controls the length of
>   time that a connection-oriented
>   connection will remain open after a
>   call to Close when data remains to be
>   sent. When you call methods to send
>   data to a peer, this data is placed in
>   the outgoing network buffer. This
>   property can be used to ensure that
>   this data is sent to the remote host
>   before the Close method drops the
>   connection.

Comment: Didn't work too well maybe I'm not using it properly? `socket.LingerState = new LingerOption(true, 3);
socket.Send(new byte[] { 0 });
socket.Close();` sends the zero byte only 1 in 10 times... ehhhh you know what I'll just leave them open i figure they will close sooner or later anyways

Comment: Try setting `socket.NoDelay = true` and also increasing `3` to let's say `30`.

Comment: no change. `socket.LingerState = new LingerOption(true, 30);
                                    socket.NoDelay = true;` I guess what it means the data placed on the outgoing network buffer will stay there for some time. maybe even a minute.. and thats too long of a wait my client even times out in 3-5 seconds.

Comment: @SSpoke - can you show your code? It is a little difficult to tell without understanding what you are doing. Can you make a simple server and client applications and paste the code to your question? This will help to provide a better answer.

Comment: That might be more difficult then the actual question haha.. well time consuming. The client is not written in C# hell I don't even have the source code to it. Well I'm trying to prevent zombie connections. The client works good at the moment it drops the connection when invalid username/password.. but sometimes a fake client may connect such as telnet etc.. and it will just hang there until I close telnet.. I want to set a time out for this to automatically close even though telnet is opened and fully connected yet.. I want to let telnet know yes you have been disconnected.  setsocketopt.

Comment: @SSpoke - it depends on your architecture. The way I handle this: I have 3 threads per client: receiver, sender and processor. Every time receiver and sender have LastActivityDateTime, which is the last time something was sent or received. The processor checks on the activity, if there is no activity for certain period the processor closes releases both sender and receiver and closes connection.

Comment: haha wow.. many people who make servers they never say to do thread per connection model. It will really lag/delay when too much connections connected to server. I have controlled thread pool which increases more threads for use every 100 connections. But all connections are kept in a List and processed by this pool, I mean sure everytime i loop all connections i can check for last activity drop inactives yah i'll go with that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are talking about the TCP protocol.
If you want to make sure that something has been received by the client, then the client needs to send a response for the last received message (e.g. bad password) and the server closes the connection after receiving the confirmation or when there was a readtimeout.

Comment: Client doesn't send any responses I have no access to modify the client. Honestly all I want is to avoid deadlocked connections from fake clients pretending to be a client like telnet etc, I also want to let these fake clients know why they got disconnected etc. You know what I'll just leave it.. i know in C++ you can do this with `setsocketopt`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e160993d.aspx  - C# way to access socket options.